# Pulling information from 2 sources and counting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I've been asked to create a system at work which logs the number of calls made and received through our VoIP system. I could have potentially done this if I were able to change the structure on datasources, but in this case I'm not allowed to change it, which now relies on me asking someone with a bit more expertise than myself.

Datasource 1 (Using MSSQL) - This logs the users who have logged in to our intranet and what their extension is:

```
+-------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| ID    | USERNAME       | EXTENSION    | LOGGEDIN            |
+-------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1     | JESS           | 101          | 2014-11-10 12:00:00 |
+-------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 2     | SARAH          | 203          | 2014-11-10 12:21:00 |
+-------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 3     | FERN           | 124          | 2014-11-10 12:21:31 |
+-------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 4     | SARAH          | 101          | 2014-11-10 13:12:00 |
+-------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

Datasource 2 (Using MySQL) - Datasource 2 contains all calls made and received using the VoIP system

```
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| ID    | SRC            | DST           | TIME                |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 1     | 101            | 02035654684   | 2014-11-10 12:01:00 |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 2     | 203            | 02087816328   | 2014-11-10 12:22:00 |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 3     | 124            | 02078939273   | 2014-11-10 12:23:31 |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 4     | 101            | 04672738782   | 2014-11-10 13:15:00 |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 5     | 07863522413    | 101           | 2014-11-10 13:21:00 |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 6     | 02076352423    | 203           | 2014-11-10 13:25:31 |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 7     | 07836325726    | 101           | 2014-11-10 13:56:00 |
+-------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

This is what I would like to be able to print:

```
+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| ID    | USERNAME       | INCOMING     | OUTGOING     | TOTAL       |
+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1     | JESS           | 0            | 1            | 1           |
+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2     | SARAH          | 2            | 2            | 4           |
+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| 3     | FERN           | 0            | 1            | 1           |
+-------+----------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

As you can see from the tables above, Sarah started off on extension 203 and then logged in to 101 after Jess had left. She made 1 call whilst logged in on 203 and 1 call whilst logged in at 101. She also picked up 2 calls whilst logged in at extension 101.

I will be using PHP for this project. Ideally, I would like to sort the table above by total descending, but I'm confident I could figure this out on my own, once I have the building blocks.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide on this.

Note: I have considered creating a temporary table that pulls the information, but I've already been told that this would be a bad idea because of the execution time of the query and how frequently I need to pull the information. The script will run every 10 seconds so whatever query I use needs to be quite lean.

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with?   How far have you gotten?

Comment: I suggest setting up a linked server from ms sql to mysql and writing a stored procedure that assembles the data.

Comment: @TabAlleman I haven't written any SQL statements yet because I'm not quite sure how to tackle the problem, hence why I'm here.

Comment: @DanBracuk This is a viable option but I don't know if that will give me real time information. I could poll the databases every few seconds I suppose.

Comment: Since you're summing total number of calls you just need to poll for those that changed since the last time and add it to a cached sum.

Comment: As @DanBracuk said use a linked server in MSSQL Server to your MySQL Database. Then use either a stored proc (as suggested) or a view to define the layout you want in php or whatever front end you end up using. The linked server gets the data realtime so no "polling the database" required.

I am assuming you are trying to create somekind of performance dashboard. If you have a SQL Server Reporting Services instance configured i'd write the report in that, you can automatically set how often to refresh the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   u.ID,
   u.USERNAME,
   coalesce(tSRC.INCOMING,0) as INCOMING,
   coalesce(tDST.OUTGOING,0) as OUTGOING,
   (coalesce(tSRC.INCOMING,0)+coalesce(tDST.OUTGOING,0)) as total
FROM
table1 u
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT a.SRC as ext , count(a.ID) as INCOMING
   FROM table2 a WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(a.SRC)=3 GROUP BY a.SRC
   ) tSRC ON tSRC.ext = u.EXTENSION
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT b.SRC as ext , count(b.ID) as OUTGOING
   FROM table2 b WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(b.DST)=3 GROUP BY b.DST
   ) tDST ON tDST.ext = u.EXTENSION
```

**edit: Better version:**

```
SELECT
   u.ID,
   u.USERNAME,
   u.EXTENSION,
   COUNT(distinct a.ID) as INCOMING,
   COUNT(distinct b.ID) as OUTGOING,
   (COUNT(distinct a.ID)+COUNT(distinct b.ID)) as TOTAL
FROM
table1 u
LEFT JOIN table2 a ON u.EXTENSION=a.SRC
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON u.EXTENSION=b.DST
GROUP BY u.EXTENSION
```

Comment: Thanks David, I trust this would work if the tables were in the same databse, but they're not :( They are in 2 different databases using 2 different engines (Datastore 1 is MSSQL and Datastore 2 is MySQL). Can you elaborate on how I could modify this to fit my needs?

Comment: (a) mirror(eg copy) the table from one database to the other or (b) do the counting in PHP (however last time I tried to connect MSSQL database to PHP, I found it easier to export/import into MySQL instead and connect MySQL)

Comment: Also, would this work as per above if another person logged in with the same extension at a different time?

Comment: Duh, now I see. That is problem. Solo SQL solution would be 'too complex', or you can do the thing with caching, like others hinted. I would, personally, do method of side-by-side reading two sorted queries in PHP, in case you somehow manage to connect MSSQL in PHP (I heard PDO plugin can do it, somehow).

Answer (score 0):

```
$q1="SELECT USERNAME, EXTENSION, unix_timestamp(LOGGEDIN) as t FROM table1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY EXTENSION,LOGGEDIN";

$q2="
(SELECT SRC-0 as EXTENSION, 0 as side, unix_timestamp(`TIME`) as t FROM table2 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(SRC)=3 )
UNION
(SELECT DST-0 as EXTENSION, 1 as side, unix_timestamp(`TIME`) as t FROM table2 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(DST)=3 )
ORDER BY EXTENSION, t";


$r1 = $db1->query($q1);
$r2 = $db2->query($q2);

$x1 = $r1->fetch_object();
$x2 = $r2->fetch_object();

$users = array();

$future_x1 = $r1->fetch_object();

while($x1 && $x2)
{
    if( $x1->EXTENSION < $x2->EXTENSION )
    {
        $x1=$future_x1 ;
        $future_x1=$r1->fetch_object();
    }
    elseif( $x1->EXTENSION > $x2->EXTENSION )
    {
        $x2 = $r2->fetch_object();
    }
    elseif( $future_x1 && $future_x1->EXTENSION == $x1->EXTENSION && $x2->t >= $future_x1->t )
    {
        $x1=$future_x1 ;
        $future_x1=$r1->fetch_object();
    }
    else
    {
        @$users[$x1->USERNAME][$x2->side]++;
        $x2 = $r2->fetch_object();
    }
}

print_r($users);
```

This solution assumes you were able to connect to both databases from PHP and that it is affordable to read practically all rows from both tables and hold an array of size equal to number of usernames.